# ROS Answers SE migration: NO MAP DATA

Tags: navigation, mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using the Lidar from the XV-11 Neato vacuum cleaner. I have the point cloud data available and is visible in RVIZ. However, I am not able to get any map data. I get the following error message in RVIZ
No tf data.  Actual error: Fixed Frame [/neato_laser] does not exist

This is a global Status warning and is shown next to Fixed frame tab.

Kindly suggest what I should do. Also, is it even possible to get that kind of data from the Lidar unit from the XV-11 Neato.

I am working on the Ubantu version of ROS.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39156/no-map-data/) by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-07-18

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on 2012-07-19**:
Thans allenh1....
Can you elaborate where the changes can be made that are mentioned in the tutorial (for hector_slam)?
Im really in a fix here.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-20**:
Have a look at the tutorial: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot

**Comment by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on 2012-07-21**:
Im getting this error when I run RVIZ. I also tried to put all the 3 options listed.

Message from [/neato_laser_publisher] has a non-fully-qualified frame_id [neato_laser]. Resolved locally to [/neato_laser].  This is will likely not work in multi-robot systems.  This message will only print once.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-23**:
I suspect you set the fixed frame to neato_laser? Then the message is OK. For mapping you probably want /map as the fixed frame.

**Comment by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on 2012-07-23**:
Thanks. But the hector_slam is not working. Where do i implement it?
It keeps saying that no such package available.

Again, I am using the ELECTRIC version of ROS.

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-23**:
So are you running any SLAM node? If not that would explain why you don't have a map. For obtaining hector_slam, just click on any of the links here, you can also use gmapping.

**Comment by [rzv0004](https://answers.ros.org/users/2525/rzv0004/) on 2012-07-23**:
After I changed the fixed frame to /map the following error appeared.
For frame [neato_laser]: Fixed Frame [/map] does not exist
I tried to install the hector_slam_launch package but I got the message that no such package exists. I tried rosmake, rosdep, and rosdep install commands. None worked.HELP

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-07-24**:
Did you install and rosmake the hector_slam stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do you have something that provides tf?
Your robot should be setup to provide /base_link -> /neato_laser (or whatever frame the laser is published in) and also send /odom -> /base_link. For mapping you will also need to run SLAM, e.g. gmapping.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2012-07-18**:
http://ros.org/wiki/tf You can use the static transform there. If you just want to map with laser data, try hector_slam: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_slam